# UIGestureRecognizer - detecting tap and drag like trackpad

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there any way to cascade UIGestureRecognizers to detect a tap and then drag.
For example, I want to detect when the user taps and then drags his finger around.

This would be similar how drag works on trackpads.

So I want to detect a tap, then I want to get UIPanGestureRecognizer to send me continuous updates.

I want to use standard UIGesture classes to create this new gesture instead of creating my own using raw touches.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Couldn't you instatiate the UIPanGestureRecognizer after detecting the tap? This approach would be between a hipothetical cascading and a raw touch manipulation.

Comment: Firstly, the setup time might be slow to initialize to detect a tap only. I also need to be able to detect a tap only also. I should have made it clear.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

although i haven't found the solution the way i expected, i found a better solution.

By just using `UILongPressGrstureRecognizer`, it is surprising that it is able to implement tap and drag.

You have to:

1. set the numberOfTapsRequired to 1 to detect the initial tap.
2. set the minimumDuration something smaller to detect drags quicker without waiting

e.g.:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *mouseDrag = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDrag:)];
mouseDrag.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
mouseDrag.minimumPressDuration=0.05;
[clickLeft requireGestureRecognizerToFail:mouseDrag];
```

to handle the drag, you must determine the state to handle it appropriately as a continuous gesture.

Comment: This worked great, thanks! One question, though: the default `numberOfTapsRequired` of 0 worked fine for me -- what issue did you have with it?

Comment: Also used number of taps 0 and minimum press duration 0, gave me the drag behavior I was looking for (gripper button).  Seems that you'd use number of taps 1 if you want to use the "Drag Lock" style behavior of Tap Pad.

Comment: This cause unnecessary delay of touching button. Try it. This solution cannot be used if you have a button below that subview where mouseDrag gesture was added.