# How to add UITapGesture and touch both to a single UIImageView in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

when i double tap on image then the image will show in complete view and at the same time i have to drag the image from one place to another in the same view.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Using the above methods the drag and drop of image is implemented successfully but the UITapGesture is not working now. So, how can I implement both ? ``

Comment: 1. have you call super in these three methods? 2. have you set the imageView userInteractionEnabled ?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260216/uigesturerecognizer-detecting-tap-and-drag-like-trackpad. Hope this helps you.

Comment: have you set self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: userInteraction is enabled.. but still TapGesture not working

Answer (score 2):

By just using UILongPressGrstureRecognizer, it is surprising that it is able to implement tap and drag.

As you just drag first Action will be Tap by default.

You have to:

set the numberOfTapsRequired to 1 to detect the initial tap.
set the minimumDuration something smaller to detect drags quicker without waiting
e.g.:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *mouseDrag = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDrag:)];
mouseDrag.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
mouseDrag.minimumPressDuration=0.05;
[clickLeft requireGestureRecognizerToFail:mouseDrag];
```

to handle the drag, you must determine the state to handle it appropriately as a continuous gesture.

Answer (score 0):

For tap gesture you can simply use

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

While you tap on image this method invoke

```
- (void) handleTapFrom: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    //Code to handle the gesture
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the simultaneous recognition?

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Single Tap in viewDidLoad method,first set the tapGesture Recognizer

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Then method

```
-(void)handleSingleTap
{
   NSLog(@"The single tap happened");
}
```

Touch Events

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  if (touch.tapCount == 1) {
     NSLog(@"The single tap happened now");
  }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  NSLog(@"The tap count is - %lu",(unsigned long)touch.tapCount);
  if (touch.tapCount == 1) 
  {  
    NSLog(@"The single tap Ended now");
  }
}
```

Comment: I have done like this only, but only touch event is happening. Tap is not working

Comment: What do you use? I mean stroybora or xib?

Comment: Then did you hook up the imageview with xib or storyboard properly?

Comment: I am doing it with storyboard. Everything is proper there. don't know where is the prob. Continuosly debugging but it is going only in the touch methods. Tap method is not called even .

Comment: My code works 100 percentage if you hook up the imageView with storyboard correctly.Then very important thing is imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES must be in your coding.Apply my code again.